# ESLint Expected to return a value at the end of method

Tags: vue.js, eslint

i have this code

```node
computed: {
   termOptions() {
      if (this.newSchedule.originCharges.serviceType !== 'If Any') {
        return this.serviceOptions.filter((val) => val.name !== 'If Any');
      }
    },
    isMoreThanToday() {
      if (this.newSchedule.validFrom) {
        const date = new Date();
        const isMore = this.newSchedule.validFrom < date.getDate();
        return isMore;
      }
    },
}
```

and i got an error saying expected return value at the of method. Is there any way to fix this? thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error?

Answer (score 5):

This is `ESLint` error. It tells you that a computed property should always `return` some value.

Your computed properties `return` values only when the condition of the `if` is `true` and don't return anything when it's `false`.

```node
computed: {
  termOptions() {
    if (this.newSchedule.originCharges.serviceType !== 'If Any') {
      return this.serviceOptions.filter((val) => val.name !== 'If Any');
    }
    else {
      return []
    }
  },
  isMoreThanToday() {
    if (this.newSchedule.validFrom) {
      const date = new Date();
      const isMore = this.newSchedule.validFrom < date.getDate();
      return isMore;
    } 
    else {
      return false
    }
  },
}
```

See [this page](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/return-in-computed-property.md) for details.